# How open the current directory on Git Bash in windows using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows, git, keyboard-shortcuts

In my Windows laptop i want to set a shortcut key such that whenever I click on the shortcut keys from my keyboard it will open the Git Bash in the current directory and the path would also be the current directory in Git Bash.

Example:
Let i have choose a shortcut Ctrl + G. So, i want that whenever i click on Ctrl+G it will open a git bash and the path on Git bash should be the current directory from where i have entered the shortcut keys.

Inplace of opening Git Bash from right-context, i want to do the same from keyboard only by clicking some key combination to open the Git Bash.

Unable to find any solution to this query. In place of it there are solution to setup on right-click context and i want it to do with the help of keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an AutoHotkey script as [in here](https://superuser.com/a/205368/141) to open a CMD in the current path.

Except instead of opening a new CMD, you can run `bash --login`, assuming `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` is in your %PATH%.

```
Run,  cmd /K (start /d "C:\your\path" bash --login)
```

Comment: Isn't possible to setup my own hotkey without opening the right-click context menu and opening the cmd or Git.

Comment: @HarsitAgarwalla True, but once set up, your hotkey script will react to a specific keystrokes combination. No context-menu or CMD then.